# Strongly typed configuration is not registered but still retrieved from ServiceProvider

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, configuration, service-provider

I wrote a test that checks that every ...Configuration class in my project (I have several of them) is resolved when I call serviceProvider.GetRequiredService. The test works, but I don't understand why it works also when I remove the registration for a class: I just need to register a single configuration. For example:

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("./Configurations/appsettings1.json");

    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    //services.Configure<ActorSystemConfiguration>(configuration.GetSection("ActorSystem"));

    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var configurationSection = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<ElasticSearchConfiguration>>();

    Assert.Equal("elasticsearchserverurl", configurationSection.CurrentValue.ServerUrl);
}
```

if I run the test in this way, without any call to services.Configure, then I get the expected behaviour with a "No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsMonitor`1[TNW.Server.Configurations.ElasticSearchConfiguration]' has been registered." exception.

If I remove the comment on the line about services.Configure (note: about another configuration section!) then I always get an empty but not null configuration object.
From the documentation GetRequiredService should throw the exception and GetService should return a null object.

I want to understand what is going on in order to be sure that I am not doing anything wrong and eventually I don't need to care about missing registrations here.

Comment: It doesn't quite work the way you suggest. The call to `Configure` that you've commented out registers the options pattern _generally_ (i.e. using `AddOptions`), which registers an open-generic version of `IOptions<>` et al. That means you'll always get an empty instance of `IOptions<T>` et al from DI once you indirectly call `AddOptions`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I expected a different behaviour and I think that with this approach there is an high risk to forget to register a configuration section and to realize it because at runtime the object is always not null, but I will keep it into account. Thanks!